# GET error using react-stripe-checkout, net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

My back-end server is up and running. No problems on that side.
But on my front-end, when I load into the page containing the stripe checkout button, I get the error. And when I click on the button I get a bunch of "failed to load resource" errors. I'm not sure how to expand on this error, the error is accompanied with a long url which I'll append at the bottom. I have gone through the internet and was not able to find a similar issue with a solution.

my component below:

```
import React from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import axios from 'axios';

const StripeCheckoutButton = ({ price }) => {
  const priceForStripe = price * 100;
  const publishableKey = 'pk_test_6y*************';

  const onToken = token => {
    axios({
      url: 'payment',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        amount: priceForStripe,
        token: token
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        alert('Payment Successfull!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Payment Error: ', console.log(error.message));
        alert('There was an issue with your Payment! Please use the provided credit card info.');
      });
  }

  return (
    <StripeCheckout 
      label='Pay Now'
      name='Crown Clothing Ltd.'
      billingAddress
      shippingAddress
      image='https://sendeyo.com/up/d/f3eb2117da'
      description={`Your total is $${price}`}
      amount={priceForStripe}
      panelLabel='Pay Now'
      token={onToken}
      stripeKey={publishableKey}
    />
  );
}

export default StripeCheckoutButton;
```

the urls in the error:

https://q.stripe.com/?event=checkout.config.summary&rf=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcheckout&sc=&optchecker-origin=configure&optchecker-numErrors=0&optchecker-numWarnings=0&distinct_id=5bc50a5a-d3bc-56aa-9c8c-1e091f6a7712&eventId=f70f82d3-6f6d-21f9-cb99-9cc0594e70e5&option-key=pk_test_6yhlzR96RC4tBigWRKiPtlIV00iuUf9b6m&h=768&w=1366&lsid=53b5a4be-b37f-4749-9ed6-f33ce3db38e2&cid=de787f0d-a3c9-46d3-95a7-efb4b79d7894&i=1580345068891

https://q.stripe.com/?event=checkout.config.summary&rf=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcheckout&sc=&optchecker-origin=configure&optchecker-numErrors=0&optchecker-numWarnings=0&distinct_id=5bc50a5a-d3bc-56aa-9c8c-1e091f6a7712&eventId=f70f82d3-6f6d-21f9-cb99-9cc0594e70e5&option-key=pk_test_6yhlzR96RC4tBigWRKiPtlIV00iuUf9b6m&h=768&w=1366&lsid=53b5a4be-b37f-4749-9ed6-f33ce3db38e2&cid=de787f0d-a3c9-46d3-95a7-efb4b79d7894&i=1580345068891

edit: since i've posted the question, i have tried to run my project from two other PCs and it works alright there. seems to be an issue with my own laptop. i believe it might have to do with an adblock of some kind. i have always had problem with loading ads for some reason, even though i don't have any adblock installed

Comment: While not the answer to your exact question, I would highly recommend not using this code. It uses Legacy Checkout which Stripe deprecated over a year ago now. You should look at the new version instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Comment: i have added an edit expanding on my question, what i used works in other computers @koopajah

Comment: those warnings are just internal to Legacy Checkout/Stripe analytics and are not showing a problem/issue. Ultimately I highly recommend moving off of Legacy Checkout as you're just getting started. Use the new version: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout